# connecting an android device with a java server

Tags: java, android, tcp

I have to create an application in `Android` the gets from the GPS some data that needs to be stored in a DB at a Java server.

The problem I'm facing is that I don't know what protocol to use for connecting these devices.
Some say that I should use `TCP/IP` .Has anyone any clue why is this better than any other protocol? like `http` for example or any `web service`?

> What I need to send between these 2 devices is some `objects` of this type:

```
class Date{

String s1;
String s2;
Float f1;
int i1;

}
```

So, I'm sending on the remote side objects of this type: `d1=new Date();` continously.
I mean that the data comes from a moving object....which moves about 8 hours a day...So during those 8 hours at intervals of 5-10 minutes I'm sending data!

Which is better and why?:D
Thank u!

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. It all depends on what your Android app is being used for and why. For example if the data only needs to be uploaded once a day then it could be sent by SMS or email. If it needs to be fairly constant then TCP socket level might be better. Alternatively something in between might use HTTP or a web service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which is better and why?

That's still a bit of a subjective question as there could still be a number of ways to do this.

In light of your edited question with the data which needs to be sent and the frequency (5-10 minutes), I'd suggest you look at implementing a simple HTTP service (listener) for the server end and simply pass the data using JSON.

Coding for both of the above is relatively simple.